# C++ strings: UTF-8 or 16-bit encoding?

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, stdstring, ucs2

I'm still trying to decide whether my (home) project should use [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) strings (implemented in terms of std::string with additional UTF-8-specific functions when necessary) or some 16-bit string (implemented as std::wstring). The project is a programming language and environment (like VB, it's a combination of both).

There are a few wishes/constraints:

- It would be cool if it could run on limited hardware, such as computers with limited memory.
- I want the code to run on Windows, Mac and (if resources allow) Linux.
- I'll be using [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) as my GUI layer, but I want the code that interacts with that toolkit confined in a corner of the codebase (I will have non-GUI executables).
- I would like to avoid working with two different kinds of strings when working with user-visible text and with the application's data.

Currently, I'm working with std::string, with the intent of using UTF-8 manipulation functions only when necessary. It requires less memory, and seems to be the direction many applications are going anyway.

If you recommend a 16-bit encoding, which one: [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)? [UCS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set#Encoding_forms_of_the_Universal_Character_Set)? Another one?

Comment: Micro ATX doesn't mean limited memory. My PC at home is on a (Micro-ATX) ASUS M2A-VM, and it runs Crysis just fine.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend UTF-16 for any kind of data manipulation and UI.
The Mac OS X and Win32 API uses UTF-16, same for wxWidgets, Qt, ICU, Xerces, and others.
UTF-8 might be better for data interchange and storage.
See http://unicode.org/notes/tn12/.

But whatever you choose, I would definitely recommend against std::string with UTF-8 "only when necessary".

Go all the way with UTF-16 or UTF-8, but do not mix and match, that is asking for trouble.

Comment: My team's Mac programmer says wchar_t is 32 bits. And there is certainly a lot of code in our codebase which would break otherwise.

Comment: Just to clarify: with "utf-8 only when necessary", I actually meant that I would be using some utf-8 manipulation functions only when I actually needed to deal with characters - but all strings would *always* be utf-8.

Comment: Accepted: I want a clear separation between GUI and data domains. The latter would be all about interchange and storage, so I don't mind the GUI layer converting to utf-16 wxStrings from utf-8 encoded std::string objects.

Comment: You might want to read this question about UTF-16: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Answer (score 26):

UTF-16 is still a variable length character encoding (there are more than 2^16 unicode codepoints), so you can't do O(1) string indexing operations. If you're doing lots of that sort of thing, you're not saving anything in speed over UTF-8. On the other hand, if your text includes a lot of codepoints in the 256-65535 range, UTF-16 can be a substantial improvement in size. UCS-2 is a variation on UTF-16 that *is* fixed length, at the cost of prohibiting any codepoints greater than 2^16.

Without knowing more about your requirements, I would personally go for UTF-8. It's the easiest to deal with for all the reasons others have already listed.

Answer (score 6):

I have never found any reasons to use anything else than UTF-8 to be honest.

Answer (score 5):

If you decide to go with UTF-8 encoding, check out this library: http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

It may make your life much easier.

Answer (score 4):

I've actually written a widely used application (5million+ users) so every kilobyte used adds up, literally. Despite that, I just stuck to wxString. I've configured it to be derived from std::wstring, so I can pass them to functions expecting a wstring const&.

Please note that std::wstring is native Unicode on the Mac (no UTF-16 needed for characters above U+10000), and therefore it uses 4 bytes/wchar_t. The big advantage of this is that i++ gets you the next character, always. On Win32 that is true in only 99.9% of the cases. As a fellow programmer, you'll understand how little 99.9% is.

But if you're not convinced, write the function to uppercase a std::string[UTF-8] and a std::wstring. Those 2 functions will tell you which way is insanity.

Your on-disk format is another matter. For portability, that should be UTF-8. There's no endianness concern in UTF-8, nor a discussion over the width (2/4). This may be why many programs appear to use UTF-8.

On a slightly unrelated note, please read up on Unicode string comparisions and normalization. Or you'll end up with the same bug as .NET, where you can have two variables föö and föö differing only in (invisible) normalization.

Comment: Note that using UTF32 on mac uses a lot of memory. The 0.1% case you mention means that any wstring on Mac will be twice as large as the same string in UTF16 on Windows (I won't even mention Linux's char). This *is* one of the reasons Linux use UTF-8 char, and why Windows uses UTF-16 wchar_t.

Answer (score 2):

MicroATX is pretty much a standard PC motherboard format, most capable of 4-8 GB of RAM. If you're talking picoATX maybe you're limited to 1-2 GB RAM. Even then that's plenty for a development environment. I'd still stick with UTF-8 for reasons mentioned above, but memory shouldn't be your concern.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: Ah, thanks.  Didn't know about that feature.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read, it's better to use a 16-bit encoding internally unless you're short on memory. It fits almost all living languages in one character

I'd also look at [ICU](http://www.icu-project.org/). If you're not going to be using certain STL features of strings, using the ICU string types might be better for you.

Comment: Actually, UTF-16 will fit most living language characters in two bytes; take a look at the [code point charts][http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/] for code points above U+10000; they're all ancient Greek or Roman symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using wxStrings? If I remember correctly, they can do utf-8 <-> Unicode conversions and it will make it a bit easier when you have to pass strings to and from the UI.